# How to force KinD cluster to auto-start with Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker-desktop, kind

I'm using Docker Desktop 4.20 to setup a KinD cluster. The cluster is working fine, however, if I re-login or restart Docker Desktop, the control plane container is gone. It seems like there is no restart policy for the container.

If, for example, I have control over the `docker run` command line, I can always specify `--restart always` which correctly ensures my container starts with Docker Desktop automatically. However, since I do NOT have control over the command that launches the cluster's control plane container, I can't tell it to always restart. I've also looked in the [KinD cluster config](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#configuring-your-kind-cluster) docs but found nothing.

How do I get the cluster to auto-restart with Docker Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You can see a GitHub issue relevant to your question [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/2631).

The thread contains useful info about restart policy options of docker containers and the kind project's decision to use a restart policy of --restart=on-failure:1.

Bottom line is, you could maybe use docker's --restart flag to configure some container restart options, kind has it documented in this [go file](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/blob/3844d0cda7f853f779788d67e1c3f70be0133622/pkg/cluster/internal/providers/docker/provision.go#L142C3-L166C28).